# How to acoustically model an irregular woodwind instrument (such as this specific case)?

Tags: acoustics, resource-recommendations, models

I'll explain what I mean by "irregular". Most woodwinds simply have a mouthpiece at one end where the sound enters, and another end where the sound leaves, while tone holes along the instrument shape the sound wave. However, what if the sound entered at somewhere along the middle of the instrument, and not at one of the ends? I know the flute's (which is what I specialize in) blow hole isn't located exactly at the end, but the acoustic model of sound-in-on-one-side-then-out-the-other still applies to the flute if you make some generalizations, especially since the distance between the flute's blow hole and the closed cork end is so insignificant that it doesn't mess up calculations that much after all these generalizations. Despite all this, there is a *specific case* that I want to mathematically model which falls under this definition of irregular.

I will now describe this specific case. I don't want to get into this too much, but this is a woodwind instrument that I've always wanted to mathematically model and hopefully invent one day. Wishful thinking, really, but I would at least like to try and mathematically model the instrument. The instrument is shaped like a thin cane that is blown into from the apex of the cane. Think of it as two pipes connected by a u-pipe, except the u-pipe is so thin width-wise that the two parallel pipes are actually touching eachother. This is so that the instrument can be played like a regular woodwind instrument, downwards like a clarinet or an oboe, since it would be kind of awkward if you were to hold and play a horizontal pipe like the flute while blowing into a hole in the center, especially if it had considerable length. When I say center, I'm being misleading. Now, if we were to take this cane and stretch it out into a horizontal pipe, the hole in which you blow is located at exactly 1/4 of the instrument's length from the the end (at least, one of them, since I never defined which end was which). I will make a sketch of the basic shape of the instrument so that you can get an idea of what I mean:

[image: Basic Instrument Model]

In this model, we have two different figures. The one of the left is the actual instrument, while the one on the right is the instrument when unbent and straightened out. *Black indicates* the pipe wall (or whatever you call that), *Yellow* indicates the airway, *Red* indicates the ends of the instrument, *Dark Blue* indicates the blow hole, and the *Light Blue* ladder-like structure attached to the right figure indicates a division of the instrument's length into 4 (remember, the blow hole would be located at 1/4 of the length of the instrument away from the end, which is also indicated in the figure). The figures are not at all to scale, *especially not to eachother*!

I know this is asking a LOT, and I'm not really expecting any of you to completely and thoroughly answer this question. What I'm asking for is mostly basic info about the acoustics (such as how I would go about calculating the fundamental frequency of this instrument, the effect of closing one of the ends, etc.). I would also like for you to provide some readings/articles/textbooks that go in-depth into topics that would help me go after modeling this instrument.

Also, I would like to maybe privately chat with you through e-mail so that we can discuss this further, if you're interested. Perhaps we could embark on a project in which we could completely develop this instrument? Very unlikely, just a fantasy of mine. A single answer would still work, and I will continue to study acoustics further.

Comment: Including resource recommendations tags might be an idea, if you want literature, as  you will only get condensed answers here, I think.  You could also study the acoustics of related instruments. Please one favor, I guess you intend it for orchestral or small  group arrangement, but if are using it for jazz , make it sound like a clarinet.  Most  jazz (post  Miles D.)  sounds to me like a fire in a pet shop. The very best of luck with it.

Comment: It's already been done. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arghul (and to keep @AlternativeFacts happy, it even sounds a bit like a clarinet!)

Comment: @alephzero I wasn't intending to be original. In fact, this will help me greatly, since I didn't know such an instrument existed.

Comment: @alephzero However, the arghul still isn't enough for my purposes.

Comment: @alephzero nicely and quickly sourced, I will search on YouTube  thank you.